# Return boolean type instead of integer in DB View

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a Database view that has the following statement:

```
SELECT
  adherence_date,
  patient_id,
  sum(case when scheduled_time = 'morning'   then nvl2(acknowledged_at,1,0) end) as morning,
  sum(case when scheduled_time = 'afternoon' then nvl2(acknowledged_at,1,0) end) as afternoon,
  sum(case when scheduled_time = 'evening'   then nvl2(acknowledged_at,1,0) end) as evening,
  sum(case when scheduled_time = 'night'     then nvl2(acknowledged_at,1,0) end) as night
FROM medication_adherences
GROUP BY adherence_date, patient_id
```

This returns records in the following format:

```
[0] #<AdherenceActivity:0x007fec986b5328> {
        :adherence_date => Wed, 01 Nov 2017,
            :patient_id => 10000,
               :morning => 1.0,
             :afternoon => 1.0,
               :evening => 0.0,
                 :night => nil
    }
```

`1 == true`, `0 == false`, and `nil` meaning no data yet

I'd like it to treat morning, afternoon, evening, or night as a Boolean instead of an integer. Is this a result of the SUM function, or an issue with my ORM? If it's due to the SUM function, how can I have it return a boolean instead of an integer?

Comment: Oracle does not support a `boolean` type in SQL. So using 0/1 is your only option (or strings like `'true'` or `'false'`)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name so what I'm doing is correct? My only other option is to work with my ORM to interpret 1/0 as a boolean?